# How to run Jenkins in test mode with all automatic triggers disables?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to find a way to disable automatic job execution on all jenkins jobs on a stage instance.

We are using jenkins-job-builder to create and update more than 1000 jobs and I want to populate a staging instance with the same jobs I have on production but I want to avoid triggering them on schedulers.

So far I identified two sources that need to be disabled:

- timer schedule
- gerrit trigger

I do know what disabling jobs does have this effect but this also prevents people from manually triggering these jobs, and for staging instance that's in fact the only kind of job triggering that I want to keep enabled.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I have not found any built-in or plugin that does this.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote 2 groovy scripts for the exact use case.

Stop TimerTrigger and PeriodicTrigger jobs:

```
/**
*
* This script disables all jobs that have TimerTrigger or PeriodicFolderTrigger (WorkflowMultiBranchProject)
*
* */
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.triggers.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger

def items = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems()
items.each { item ->
    if(item.hasProperty('triggers')){
        item.triggers.values().each { trigger ->
            if(trigger instanceof TimerTrigger || trigger instanceof PeriodicFolderTrigger) {
                println "Disabling project with timer trigger: ${item.name}"
                item.setDisabled(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stop SCMTrigger jobs (same idea, different Trigger class)

```
/**
 *
 * This script disables all jobs with SCM trigger
 *
 * */
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.triggers.*

def items = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems()
items.each { item ->
    if(item.hasProperty('triggers')){
        item.triggers.values().each { trigger ->
            if(trigger instanceof SCMTrigger) {
                println "Disabling project with SCM trigger: ${item.name}"
                item.setDisabled(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```